# Referring to properties passes as props in Vue.js components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've started working on a board game prototype and decided to go with Vue.js. I have some experience with JavaScript and everything was going fine ... until I tried to access a property passed with 'props' in a component.

Here's the whole code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Board</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  
  <style type="text/css">
    #board {
      width: 600px;
    }
    .square { width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 1px; border: 1px solid grey; display: inline-block; float: left; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="board">
    
    <square v-for="square in squares"></square>
    
  </div>
  
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#board',
      data: {
        squares: []
      }
    })
    
    const rows = 5
    const cols = 5
    const reservedLocation = { row: 2, col: 2 }
    
    Vue.component('square', {
      props: [
        'row',
        'col',
        'type',
      ],
      template: '<div class="square" v-on:click="logLocation"></div>',
      methods: {
        logLocation: function() {
          console.log(this)
          console.log("Location: " + this.col + "x" + this.row )
        },
      },
    })
    
    for (var row=0; row<rows; row++) {
      for (var col=0; col<cols; col++) {
        const type = (row == reservedLocation.row && col == reservedLocation.col) ? 'reserved' : 'empty'
        app.squares.push({ row: row, col: col, type: type })
      }
    }
    
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

What's happening there is the "board" div is filled with the "square" components. Each square component has the 'row', 'col' and 'type' properties, passed to it as 'props'. When the user click on a square, the 'logLocation' function of the corresponding component is called and all that function does is, it logs the 'row' and 'col' properties.

Everything works fine except the message logged is: "Location: undefinedxundefined", in other words, both this.col and this.row seems to be undefined. I've checked 'this', and it seems to be the correct component.

I'm sure it's something obvious but I couldn't find an answer in either the official documentation, in tutorials or even here, on Stack Overflow itself – perhaps I'm not using the correct terms.

A bit of new info: the 'row' and 'col' properties are set on the component object and in the '$props' property but the value they return in 'undefined'. Am I, somehow, passing the parameters incorrectly?

---

### Solution

Turns out, there is a section in the Vue.js documentation dedicated specifically to using 'v-for' with components: ["v-for with a Component"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component) and here's the relevant portion of the code:

```html
  <div id="board">
    
    <square
      v-for="square in squares"
      :key="square.id"
      :row="square.row"
      :col="square.col"
      :type="square.type"
    ></square>
    
  </div>
```

Huge thanks to Stephen Thomas for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the props correctly, and you're accessing the props correctly, but you haven't actually set them to any value. The markup:

```
<square v-for="square in squares"></square>
```

doesn't pass the props to the component. Perhaps you want something like

```
<div v-for="row in rows" :key="row">
    <div v-for="col in cols" :key="col">
        <square :row="row" :col="col"></square>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That must be it! There is a message alluding to that in the console too: "<square v-for="square in squares">: component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys." Thank you so much! That leaves me to research how to do that without the explicit markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

> console.log("Location: " + this.$props.col + " x " + this.$props.row )

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply! I've checked it out and added a note at the end of my question. Unfortunately this doesn't work either as the properties, for some reason, return 'undefined'. The issue now seems to be not with accessing the properties, but with setting them in the first place?